# Routing Error uninitialized constant BookingtableController -ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Showing routing error-uninitialized constant BookingtableController

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :booking_table 
  resources :restaurant_table
  root 'bookingtable#index'
  post 'bookingtable/booking'
  get 'bookingtable/booking'
  get 'bookingtable/index'
  post 'bookingtable/index'

  resources :booking_table do
    post :booking, on: :collection, as: :booking
  end
end
```

BookingtableController.rb

```
class BookingTableController < ApplicationController

def booking
end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag({:controller=>"BookingtableController", :action=>"booking"},     method: :booking) do %>

  <!--here action is whisch page it will go  after method functionality execution -->

  <div class="center-data">Insert,Join,fetch:

  </div>
   <div class="ebutton">
      <%= submit_tag "Enter" %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Did you tried my answer below?

Comment: index.html.erb is under views/booking_table

Comment: changed the routes still showing that error @HashRocket

Comment: After you change your routes, did you try to restart your server?

Comment: You need to restart your rails server after adding/modifying routes. If you `CamelCase` in your controller, you must write it in your routes as `snake_case`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following on your routes.

From:

```
root 'bookingtable#index'
post 'bookingtable/booking'
get 'bookingtable/booking'
get 'bookingtable/index'
post 'bookingtable/index'
```

To:

```
root 'booking_table#index'
post 'booking_table/booking'
get 'booking_table/booking'
get 'booking_table/index'
post 'booking_table/index'
```

You should camelcase your routes related to `BookingTable`.

Then ofcourse, you created some actions in your routes. Then you must created those in your controller.

**UPDATE**

Change your index to:

```
<%= form_tag({:controller=>"booking_table", :action=>"booking"},     method: :booking) do %>
```

**UPDATE 2**
Change your filename `BookingtableController.rb`.

From:

```
BookingtableController.rb
```

To:

```
booking_table_controller.rb
```

Please follow the rails conventions.